# Sharepoint REST api upload file using the Add function in c# with escaped characters

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, file-upload

I'm trying to upload some files to sharepoint using the REST API and the add function.

I have this working for file names such as: 'Valid - Document.doc'

However if the file name contains an '&', such as: 'Valid & Document.doc', I get a 400 (Bad request) error from the API.

My code to upload looks like:

```
var encodedFileName = Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName);
var addFileCommand = $"_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/{folderPath}')/Files/add(url='{encodedFileName}', overwrite=false)";
```

I then call Post with the file data and the URL. Even with `Uri.EscapeDataString` so the & now becomes %26, I still get the 400 Bad request error.

Can the REST API be used to upload documents with '&' in their file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint Server 2013 it is simply because the character is illegal. It seems it is not illegal in SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2016.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Invalid-characters-in-file-or-folder-names-or-invalid-file-types-in-OneDrive-for-Business-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa